# Telegram bot made with telegram-bot-sdk and Laravel stop working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot embedded in an application made with Laravel (^6) and Vue (^2.6.12) and PHP (^8.0). The bot was made using the "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk" (^3.0) and once given the /start command it should respond with "Hello! Please enter your phone number. Ex: 3439078235 once entered you will receive daily updates regarding the construction sites you are associated with." Once the number is entered it checks to database if that number is present and will send a series of messages from then to 4 pm. For the past month the bot has stopped registering new numbers and when you give it the /start command it does not respond, while with previously registered numbers it continues to send messages at 4 pm.

In config/telegram.php:

```
<?php

use App\Telegram\Commands\StartCommand;

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Bot Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the bots below you wish to use as
    | your default bot for regular use. Of course, you may use many
    | bots at once using the manager class.
    |
    */
    'default' => 'common',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Telegram Bots
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the telegram bots config.
    |
    | Supported Params:
    | - username: Your Telegram Bot's Username.
    |         Example: (string) 'BotFather'.
    |
    | - token: Your Telegram Bot's Access Token.
               Refer for more details: https://core.telegram.org/bots#botfather
    |          Example: (string) '123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11'.
    |
    | - commands: (Optional) Commands to register for this bot,
    |             Supported Values: "Command Group Name", "Shared Command Name", "Full Path to Class".
    |             Default: Registers Global Commands.
    |             Example: (array) [
    |               'admin', // Command Group Name.
    |               'status', // Shared Command Name.
    |               Acme\Project\Commands\BotFather\HelloCommand::class,
    |               Acme\Project\Commands\BotFather\ByeCommand::class,
    |             ]
    */
    'bots' => [
        'common' => [
            'username'  => 'Trapattoni_srl_bot',
            'token' => env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN', 'bot_token'),
            'commands' => [
                App\Telegram\Commands\StartCommand::class,
                App\Telegram\Commands\StopCommand::class
            ],
        ],

//        'second' => [
//            'username'  => 'MySecondBot',
//            'token' => '123456:abc',
//        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Asynchronous Requests [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When set to True, All the requests would be made non-blocking (Async).
    |
    | Default: false
    | Possible Values: (Boolean) "true" OR "false"
    |
    */
    'async_requests' => env('TELEGRAM_ASYNC_REQUESTS', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Client Handler [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you'd like to use a custom HTTP Client Handler.
    | Should be an instance of \Telegram\Bot\HttpClients\HttpClientInterface
    |
    | Default: GuzzlePHP
    |
    */
    'http_client_handler' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resolve Injected Dependencies in commands [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Using Laravel's IoC container, we can easily type hint dependencies in
    | our command's constructor and have them automatically resolved for us.
    |
    | Default: true
    | Possible Values: (Boolean) "true" OR "false"
    |
    */
    'resolve_command_dependencies' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Telegram Global Commands [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you'd like to use the SDK's built in command handler system,
    | You can register all the global commands here.
    |
    | Global commands will apply to all the bots in system and are always active.
    |
    | The command class should extend the \Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command class.
    |
    | Default: The SDK registers, a help command which when a user sends /help
    | will respond with a list of available commands and description.
    |
    */
    'commands' => [
        Telegram\Bot\Commands\HelpCommand::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Command Groups [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You can organize a set of commands into groups which can later,
    | be re-used across all your bots.
    |
    | You can create 4 types of groups:
    | 1. Group using full path to command classes.
    | 2. Group using shared commands: Provide the key name of the shared command
    | and the system will automatically resolve to the appropriate command.
    | 3. Group using other groups of commands: You can create a group which uses other
    | groups of commands to bundle them into one group.
    | 4. You can create a group with a combination of 1, 2 and 3 all together in one group.
    |
    | Examples shown below are by the group type for you to understand each of them.
    */
    'command_groups' => [
        /* // Group Type: 1
           'commmon' => [
                Acme\Project\Commands\TodoCommand::class,
                Acme\Project\Commands\TaskCommand::class,
           ],
        */

        /* // Group Type: 2
           'subscription' => [
                'start', // Shared Command Name.
                'stop', // Shared Command Name.
           ],
        */

        /* // Group Type: 3
            'auth' => [
                Acme\Project\Commands\LoginCommand::class,
                Acme\Project\Commands\SomeCommand::class,
            ],

            'stats' => [
                Acme\Project\Commands\UserStatsCommand::class,
                Acme\Project\Commands\SubscriberStatsCommand::class,
                Acme\Project\Commands\ReportsCommand::class,
            ],

            'admin' => [
                'auth', // Command Group Name.
                'stats' // Command Group Name.
            ],
        */

        /* // Group Type: 4
           'myBot' => [
                'admin', // Command Group Name.
                'subscription', // Command Group Name.
                'status', // Shared Command Name.
                'Acme\Project\Commands\BotCommand' // Full Path to Command Class.
           ],
        */
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Shared Commands [Optional]
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Shared commands let you register commands that can be shared between,
    | one or more bots across the project.
    |
    | This will help you prevent from having to register same set of commands,
    | for each bot over and over again and make it easier to maintain them.
    |
    | Shared commands are not active by default, You need to use the key name to register them,
    | individually in a group of commands or in bot commands.
    | Think of this as a central storage, to register, reuse and maintain them across all bots.
    |
    */
    'shared_commands' => [
        // 'start' => Acme\Project\Commands\StartCommand::class,
        // 'stop' => Acme\Project\Commands\StopCommand::class,
        // 'status' => Acme\Project\Commands\StatusCommand::class,
    ],
];
```

In app/Telegram/Commands/StartCommand.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Telegram\Commands;

use Telegram\Bot\Actions;
use Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command;

class StartCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string Command Name
     */
    protected $name = "start";

    /**
     * @var string Command Description
     */
    protected $description = "Start Command to get you started";

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // This will send a message using `sendMessage` method behind the scenes to
        // the user/chat id who triggered this command.
        // `replyWith<Message|Photo|Audio|Video|Voice|Document|Sticker|Location|ChatAction>()` all the available methods are dynamically
        // handled when you replace `send<Method>` with `replyWith` and use the same parameters - except chat_id does NOT need to be included in the array.
        $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Ciao! Inserisci il tuo numero di telefono. Es: 3439078235 una volta inserito riceverai gli aggiornamenti giornalieri riguardanti i cantieri a cui sei associato.']);

    }
}
```

I have tried clearing the Laravel cache, restarting the bot and restarting the server but no luck. I have ownership of the bot so with BotFather I can manage it. Since sending messages from the bot works I would like to avoid doing any operation that could compromise it.